# Is there a limit to a webTorrent Magnet URI length?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bittorrent, webtorrent

I'm building a library to help decentralize tracker servers. The way it works is you spin up your tracker server => it connects with a swarm of tracker servers using the same swarm ID => then it shares the tracker server location with the swarm for that app ID. P2P apps with the app ID can then announce to all of the tracker servers in the swarm with that given app ID.

What I'm wondering about is whether or not there is a limit to the length of a WebTorrent Magnet URI?

Unfortunately, the only way for browsers to connect to each other is if they share the same tracker server(s).

My tracker swarm solution causes them to announce to all of the tracker servers for that app name in that tracker swarm ID.

What is the theoretical limit, practical limit of the URI?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: does [this magnet uri wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) or [documentation page](http://magnet-uri.sourceforge.net/) help?

Comment: @JaromandaX, no, sorry.. not really. I'm trying to figure out if I have 1000 tracker servers in the swarm (for example): whether or not the magnet URI will be successful

Comment: wouldn't the tracker URL point to a resource that contains the 1000 tracker servers? I may be misunderstanding the documentation, but I don't think I am

Comment: No, the URI will contain all of the trackers in my use case.

Comment: I'm not sure there is single answer.  In practice, most clients will accept any length that you can get into them, but you'll run into limits of the shell, a GUI element, or something else first.  In general, anything below [2000 characters long is safe for a URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) but you might be able to get up to 8000, or 32767.  Beyond that is unlikely.